# Sending apikey in header, angular4

Tags: angular

I have an API REST that requires the apikey in the headers to validate, I am doing the query with angular 4, but the apikey is not sent in the headers.

If I make the query with PostMan it works without problem. I'm stuck at this point, I appreciate your help friends.

I need to send the "apikey" in the headers of the request something like that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VucjT.png)

This is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private apiURL = 'http://192.168.1.53/joinn-api/v1'
  data: any = {}

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    this.getData()
    this.getEvents()

  }

  getData(){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    headers = headers.set('apikey','!eqBwMfoWmEOWRoxxxxxxxK')
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL + '/event', {headers: headers})
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }

  getEvents(){
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })

  }
```

Comment: just use headers.append('apikey','your-api-key');

Comment: You aren't putting the API key in the headers, so it's unclear why that's surprising.

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

`const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'key1': 'value1',
      'key2': 'value2',
    // the rest ..
    });`

It works with Postman probably because you add it manually in the form.

EDIT: 
Please note that `apiKey` and `token` in the URL are different - in case you confuse them.